# .on() change & click events for a specific data going into the handler

Tags: jquery, events, handler

So here's my code

```
$the_portfolio.on('change click', '.et_pb_portfolio_filter,.et_pb_portfolio_filter a,.et_pb_portfolio_filter_all,.et_pb_portfolio_filter_all a', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
```

all I want to do is for on.change to work with all data except for .et_pb_portfolio_filter_all and .et_pb_portfolio_filter_all a. Those two should only work with on.click since it is a button

Right now the onclick also works with the dropdown menu and it's causing some issues.

Comment: Use jQuery [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just subscribe to two events separately?

```
$(the_portfolio).on('change', 
                    '.et_pb_portfolio_filter,.et_pb_portfolio_filter a', 
                     function(e){
                           e.preventDefault()
                     }
                    );

$(the_portfolio).on('click', 
                    '.et_pb_portfolio_filter,.et_pb_portfolio_filter a,.et_pb_portfolio_filter_all,.et_pb_portfolio_filter_all a', 
                     function(e){
                           e.preventDefault()
                     }
                    );
```